# can I animate an arc's end angle?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to make my arc's end angle go from X to Y.

Here's what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/97dUJ/

Can I make:

```
var endAngle = 0 * Math.PI;
```

Animate to:

```
var endAngle = 0.5 * Math.PI;
```

Not just jump to that angle, but actually animate, with a simple ease, like easeInOut or something... Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Try to do it using the new `requestAnimationFrame()` thingy, redraw a slightly longer arc over the old one after each frame is rendered. Here's a related link: http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: I'm pretty new to HTML5, any idea on how I can take that approach and apply it to that fiddle? Thanks!

Comment: I assume you're doing this for educational purposes, but if you're working on this for a commercial project (and for the benefit of anyone else reading this who may be) I'd strongly suggest looking at D3 (http://d3js.org/), as it'll do all the heavy lifting for you and let you concentrate on the end result. Happy learning!

Comment: You could try with Raphael library (ye, it has my name). Here's another question which might lead you the way: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9361476/1661358

Answer (score 2):

you could animate the endAngle property then clear the canvas and redraw the arc with the latest value, like this..

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var props = {
    x : canvas.width / 2,
    y : canvas.height / 2,
    radius : 75,
    startAngle : 0,
    endAngle : 0,
    counterClockwise : false
}

function drawArc() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(props.x, props.y, props.radius, props.startAngle, props.endAngle, props.counterClockwise);
    context.lineWidth = 15;

    // line color
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.stroke();    
}

TweenMax.to(props, 1, {endAngle: Math.PI * 2, yoyo:true, repeat:-1, ease:Quad.easeInOut, onUpdate:drawArc});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B8XCw/8/

note: this is using Tweenmax for animating the property

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy to do you just need to add a `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame` and increment the value your want to multiply the ending angle by.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/97dUJ/1/)**

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var x = canvas.width / 2;
      var y = canvas.height / 2;
      var radius = 75;
      var startAngle = 1.5 * Math.PI;
      var curVal = 0;
      var endAngle = 0 * Math.PI;
      var counterClockwise = false;

function animate(){
    if(curVal < 0.5){
      curVal+= 0.01;
    }
      endAngle = curVal * Math.PI;
      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterClockwise);
      context.lineWidth = 15;
      // line color
      context.strokeStyle = 'black';
      context.stroke();
    setTimeout(animate,30);
}

animate();
​
```

Comment: This is great example, just need to stop function from running once animation is done. Which is adding

if(curVal < 0.5){
      setTimeout(animate,30);
 }

at the end.