# Raphael arc animation is morphing instead of following arc path

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I have been able to successfully animate an arc along the path of the arc using this code

```
var archtype = Raphael("canvas", 200, 100);
archtype.customAttributes.arc = function (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
    var alpha = 360 / total * value,
        a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
        x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
        y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
        path;
    if (total == value) {
        path = [
            ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
            ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
        ];
    } else {
        path = [
            ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
            ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
        ];
    }
    return {
        path: path
    };
};

//make an arc at 50,50 with a radius of 30 that grows from 0 to 40 of 100 with a bounce
var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
    "stroke": "#f00",
    "stroke-width": 14,
    arc: [50, 50, 0, 100, 30]
});

my_arc.animate({
    arc: [50, 50, 40, 100, 30]
}, 1500, "bounce");
```

The only problem with using this code is that I need to have multiple canvas elements on the page and I don't want to have to define `archtype.customAttributes.arc` 10 times on the same page.

In order to fix this problem I thought I could just do this...

```
function arc (xloc, yloc, value, total, R) {
        var alpha = 360 / total * value,
            a = (90 - alpha) * Math.PI / 180,
            x = xloc + R * Math.cos(a),
            y = yloc - R * Math.sin(a),
            path;
        if (total == value) {
            path = [
                ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                ["A", R, R, 0, 1, 1, xloc - 0.01, yloc - R]
            ];
        } else {
            path = [
                ["M", xloc, yloc - R],
                ["A", R, R, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]
            ];
        }
        return path;
    }
var path = arc(50, 50, 0, 100, 30);
var my_arc = archtype.path().attr({
    "stroke": "#f00",
    "stroke-width": 14,
    path:path
});

var path = arc(50, 50, 40, 100, 30);
my_arc.animate({
    path:path
}, 1500, "bounce");
```

However, when I try and do it this way the end of the arc takes the straightest path to the new endpoint causing a twisting, morphing effect.

Can anyone explain why my example does this and recommend a was for me to overcome this issue without having to declare a custom attribute for every canvas i need on the page? Am I incorrect to make the assumption that `arc: [50, 50, 0, 100, 30]` is the same as `path: path`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Having the same issue - has anyone solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't give an educated answer, but solved my problem by adapting this example: http://jsfiddle.net/7jHPv/5/ quoted in this question: [Animating an arc in Raphael JS wobbles in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361476/animating-an-arc-in-raphael-js-wobbles-in-chrome)

```
    var myArc = r.path().attr({
        "stroke": arcColours[i]
    ,   "stroke-width": 6
    ,   arc: [1, 100, muffinRadius, step*(i+1), diagramHeight/2]
    });

    myArc.animate({
        arc: [values[i], 100, muffinRadius, step*(i+1), diagramHeight/2]
    }, 1500, "<>", function() {
        // anim complete here
    });
```